# Enable Apache2 Site with a2ensite and specify priority

Tags: apache-2.2

How to specify priority (site name prefix of symlink in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/) with a2ensite?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no such a possibility.
You need either to rename a symlink after a2ensite or to name your files in sites-enabled with priority prefixes.

a2ensite source code:

```
sub doit {
my $acton = shift;    
my $prio = "";
if ( $obj eq 'site' && $acton eq 'default' ) {
    $prio = '000-';
}
```

$prio is not modified anywhere else. You may modify the source code though. Not a good idea, but you can start with such a patch:

```
@@ -116,6 +116,13 @@
         $prio = '000-';
     }

+    if ( $obj eq 'site' )
+    {
+       print "Enter priority: ";
+       $prio = <STDIN>;
+       chomp $prio;
+       $prio .= '-';
+    }
     my ( $conftgt, $conflink );
     if ( $obj eq 'module' ) {
         if ( $acton eq 'cgi' && threaded() ) {
```

You'll need to enter priority manually both when enable and disable a site.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot achieve what you are attempting to do with `a2ensite`, as that tool contains special logic to identify when the `default` site is being enabled, so that it names the symlink `000-default`. This is documented in the [man page](http://man.he.net/man8/a2ensite).

Nevertheless, `a2ensite` is really just a glorified wrapper which creates symlinks in the appropriate location. Therefore, there is nothing to prevent you either:

- renaming the symlink *after* `a2ensite` has added it, to add the priority prefix number to specify the site load order
- create the symlink yourself in the first instance, without using `a2ensite`, using a command to the effect of `ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/<site> /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/nnn-<site>`, where `nnn` is the priority you wish to set. Just remember to reload Apache after having done so
- modifying the source code, although bear in mind this will give you a version of `a2ensite` which is out-of-line with other iterations in the main source tree, which could cause future upgrade difficulties (unless you get your changes merged upstream)